# JavaFx: TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Как можно сделать такие полосы (штриховку) в TreeView? 
Перегуглил как мог, нигде и намёка нет на подобную штуку

javafx: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
swing: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сейчас такого вообще никак не сделать. Сам задавался таким вопросом

Comment: А откуда вы этот скрин взяли?

Comment: Скрин взял отсюда: http://www.by-bismark.net.ua/javafx-izmenit-ikonki-dlya-treeview

Comment: @Bogdab Bida чет вранье какое-то. Этот скрин похож на свинговое дерево

Comment: Здесь 2 скрина, 2й это пример (это и есть swing), 1й доказательство возможности этого в javafx

Comment: я и говорю, что первый скрин - вранье. Я сам занимался поисками около недели, нигде не нашел инфы. На том сайте я так же не увидел исходного кода. Так что пока не будет кода/css - я в это не поверю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
TreeItem<HBox> item=new TreeItem<HBox>(new HBox(new ImageView(new Image(inputStream)),new Label("Root")));
item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<HBox>(new HBox(new ImageView(new Image(inputStream)),new Label("Item1"))));
TreeView<HBox> treeView=new TreeView<HBox>(item);
```

При желании можно сделать вместо HBox класс, который будет автоматически менять изображение в зависимости от строения TreeItem.